# Tensor components.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Let $T \in \mathcal{T}_{s}^{r}$ be a tensor such that it has the same components with respect to any basis. Show that $T=0$ or $r=s$.

Here's what I've done:

We know that $\widetilde{T}^{\text{i}'_{1}\text{i}'_{2}...\text{i}'_{r}}_{\text{j}'_{1}\text{j}'_{2}...\text{j}'_{s}} = T^{\text{i}'_{1}\text{i}'_{2}...\text{i}'_{r}}_{\text{j}'_{1}\text{j}'_{2}...\text{j}'_{s}}$. Let's suppose that $r>s$. If $r-s$ is odd, let us consider the basis $\{\tilde{e}_{\text{i}}\} = \{-e_{\text{i}}\} \quad \forall \text{i} \in \{1,...,n\}$. This implies that its dual basis is as follows $\{\tilde{\omega}_{\text{i}}\} = \{-\omega_{\text{i}}\} \quad \forall \text{i} \in \{1,...,n\}$. Then

$T^{\text{i}_{1}\text{i}_{2}...\text{i}_{r}}_{\text{j}_{1}\text{j}_{2}...\text{j}_{s}} = T(\omega^{\text{i}_1},\omega^{\text{i}_2},...,\omega^{\text{i}_r},e_{\text{j}_1},e_{\text{j}_2},...,e_{\text{j}_s}) = T(-\tilde{\omega}^{\text{i}_1},-\tilde{\omega}^{\text{i}_2},...,-\tilde{\omega}^{\text{i}_r},-\tilde{e}_{\text{j}_1},-\tilde{e}_{\text{j}_2},...,-\tilde{e}_{\text{j}_s})$

$\Rightarrow T^{\text{i}_{1}\text{i}_{2}...\text{i}_{r}}_{\text{j}_{1}\text{j}_{2}...\text{j}_{s}} = (-1)^{r-s}T(\omega^{\text{i}_1},\omega^{\text{i}_2},...,\omega^{\text{i}_r},e_{\text{j}_1},e_{\text{j}_2},...,e_{\text{j}_s}) = -T^{\text{i}_{1}\text{i}_{2}...\text{i}_{r}}_{\text{j}_{1}\text{j}_{2}...\text{j}_{s}} \quad \therefore T=0$.

I'm having trouble when $r-s$ is even. It is obvious that the basis I chose in the earlier proof doesn't work in this case, and I can't find the right basis in order to conclude that $T=0$. I know that I can always give a change of basis if there's an index that repeats itself an odd amount of times in the component, yet I'm unable to find a basis where in the component all the indices repeat themselves an even amount of times.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there.

Instead of just changing basis by multiplying each basis vector by $-1$, you can instead consider changing basis by multiplying each basis vector by some non-zero scalar $\alpha$. Then

$$T= \dots = \alpha^{s-r} T$$

so taking $\alpha$ to be anything which isn't a root of unity, like $\alpha=1/2$, gives us that $s-r=0$ and hence $s=r$.